# Подключение файла в подпапке дочерней темы wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

как подключить файл в подпапке дочерней темы Sirat /inc/social-widgets/social-icon.php ?
Я создал соответствующие папки в дочерней теме и поместил измененный файл social-icon.php по этому пути.

Пробовал так, сайт выдает ошибку
require_once get_stylesheet_directory(). '/inc/social-widgets/social-icon.php';

Comment: Какую ошибку конкретно выдаёт сайт? Код подключения правильный.

Comment: Deprecated: define(): Declaration of case-insensitive constants is deprecated in /var/www/admin/data/mysite.ru/wp-content/themes/sirat/functions.php on line 326 Fatal error: Cannot declare class Sirat_Social_Widget, because the name is already in use in /var/www/admin/data/www/mysite.ru//wp-content/themes/sirat/inc/social-widgets/social-icon.php on line 119

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить данную ошибку?почему она может вылезти если все правильно подключено?

Comment: Как я и говорил, код подключения верный. Вопрос без указания конкретной ошибки просто вводит в заблуждение. Файл у вас подключается, и ошибка возникает уже в нём. Потому что внутри файла вы пытаетесь определить класс Sirat_Social_Widget, который уже определён в другом файле.

Comment: и как быть в такой ситуации?как можно узнать конкретную ошибку?

Comment: Дать доступ к сайту человеку, который разбирается в php. Тут так не ответить - информации ноль. Гдк определён этот класс ранее, как, зачем вы его снова  тащите в своем файле, какая вообще задача.

Comment: Вы в комментарии привели конкретную ошибку "Fatal error: Cannot declare...". А вопрос без этой конкретной ошибки просто вводил в заблуждение.

Comment: может я скину вам файл который отредактированный если можно?

Comment: Нет, не надо. Или создайте новый вопрос, или полностью отредактируйте этот, с указанием всех файлов, и вашей задачи.

Comment: создал, посмотрите

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй вот эту функцию использовать get_template_directory_uri()

Плюс сделай echo и посмотри, что он к тебя вообще выводить. Скорее всего ты просто пытаешься подключить файл не по тому урлу

Comment: можно полностью код?

Comment: А ответе 2 ошибки: template_dir... - это для родительской темы. uri - для пути в url (доступ через браузер). В вопросе же надо подключить файл php внутри, в бэкенде.

Comment: Извините ребята, я с телефона