# Ошибка при подключении файла в дочерней теме wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, define

Такая проблема: 
имеется дочерняя тема Sirat, подключил отредактированный файл по пути /inc/social-widgets/social-icon.php

Подключал так:
require_once get_stylesheet_directory(). '/inc/social-widgets/social-icon.php';

После чего получаю ошибку:

Deprecated: define(): Declaration of case-insensitive constants is deprecated in /var/www/admin/data/mysite.ru/wp-content/themes/sirat/functions.php on line 326 Fatal error: Cannot declare class Sirat_Social_Widget, because the name is already in use in /var/www/admin/data/www/mysite.ru//wp-content/themes/sirat/inc/social-widgets/social-icon.php on line 119

как исправить данную проблему?
Прикладываю файлы functions.php и отредактированный в дочерней теме social-icon.php

https://yadi.sk/d/7Qr7-RcgQo-gLA
https://yadi.sk/d/SMyHI9Zb5jnYtg

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подключение файла в подпапке дочерней темы wordpress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1069846/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-wordpress)

Comment: Кря, тут вопрос уже более детально обсуждается, не подскажешь как решить проблему?

Comment: В родительской теме Sirat_Social_Widget должен быть обернут в if ( ! class_exist...). Про define можешь загуглить

Answer (score 0):

Первая ошибка - это просто NOTICE о том, что в php 7.3 изменили работу с define().

Попробуйте так, должно помочь.

```
define('SIRAT_CREDIT',__('https://www.vwthemes.com/themes/free-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/','sirat'));
```

файл functions.php, строка 326

Сам не проверял, вот тут рекомендуют: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/define-declaration-of-case-insensitive-constants-is-deprecated/

Если кратко, то без этой конструкции `__()` вот это значение `'sirat'` обрабатывается как TRUE и задает для define функции case-insensitive параметр, который в php 8 хотят удалить полностью. А с этой конструкцией define становится case_sensitive

Подробнее об этом NOTICE - https://hackernoon.com/deprecations-and-changes-for-php-7-3-avoid-errors-7a5c4dbeaa8b

Ещё можно просто отключить WP_DEBUG в wp-config поставив false, спрятав таким образом некритические ошибки. (Это костыль как по мне, но до php 8 доживете с таким подходом).

Вернуться на php 7.2 тоже вариант (тоже костыльный).

Вторая ошибка вылезает из-за того, что вы дважды пытаетесь зарегистрировать класс с одним и тем же именем `Sirat_Social_Widget`.

Замените его в файле social-icon.php с `Sirat_Social_Widget` например на `Sirat_Social_Widget_2` (во всех встречающихся местах), а так же его повторную инициализацию с `sirat_custom_load_widget` на `sirat_custom_load_widget_2`

Это должно будет исправить проблему.

Ещё обратите внимание что у вас двойной слеш в ошибке

> /var/www/admin/data/www/mysite.ru **вот тут //**  wp-content/themes/sirat/inc/social-widgets/social-icon.php

Возможно вы где-то не правильно указываете пути. Это мелочь, но глаз режет.

UPD

Вы используете `get_stylesheet_directory()` для получения пути при подключении файла вот тут:

```
require_once get_stylesheet_directory(). '/inc/social-widgets/social-icon.php';
```

Это не верно. Надо использовать `get_template_part();`

Правильно вставить в нужном месте:

```
get_template_part( 'widgets/social', 'icon' );
```

А в папке темы (там где лежит functions.php) создать подпапку с названием widgets и положить в неё файл social-icon.php

Прикрепляю переписанный файл social-icon.php Попробуйте его использовать.

https://yadi.sk/d/CB-zI5HzKDHerw

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare sirat_custom_load_widget() (previously declared in /var/www/admin/data/www/site.ru/wp-content/themes/sirat-child/inc/social-widgets/social-icon.php:81) in /var/www/admin/data/www/site.ru/wp-content/themes/sirat/inc/social-widgets/social-icon.php on line 123

после того, как исправил на Sirat_Social_Widget_2 в файле social-icon.php

Закомментировал строчки и выдало Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in

Comment: Добавь двойку к sirat_custom_load_widget чтобы стало sirat_custom_load_widget_2 в строках 80 и 83, по поводу комментирования - моя ошибка. Там весь блок подключается как класс, потому удаление недопустимо. Исправил ответ.

Comment: А тебя не смущает, что он не использует get_template_part()?

Comment: Ты про get_stylesheet_directory() xD? Даже не обратил внимание. Сейчас допишу.

Comment: блин я запутался)

Comment: Сейчас напишу тебе как надо и приложу файл куда-нибудь. Ещё как заметили ты используешь get_stylesheet_directory(), и кладешь файлы нового дизайна в папку стилей. Так делать не надо. Покажу как надо.

Comment: ок, буду благодарен)
после замены sirat_custom_load_widget_2; sirat_custom_load_widget_2
сайт грузится но ошибки наверху есть и файл вложенный в дочерке не работает

Comment: Переписал файл и прикрепил. Если вылезают ошибки, пиши какие, разберемся. Так же добавил в ответе правильный способ подключать в шаблон wordpress файлы (без require). Ухожу спать. С утра почитаю.

Comment: get_template_part тут ни к селу, ни к городу. Используется для подключения файлов темы, вроде content, navigation, pagination. Не является никаким "правильным" способом, а лишь удобным средством подключения. В то же время require не является неправильным способом подключения файлов. Совет использовать get_template_part вместо require не привязан к реальности программирования под WordPress и не имеет практического смысла.

Comment: Как по вашему мнению следует подключить файл с социальными кнопками в тему из примера? Или стоит оставить require с переменной пути до CSS папки и хранить файл блока кнопок соц сетей среди стилей?

Comment: Стили тут ни при чем. get_stylesheet_directory() задает путь до корневой папки дочерней темы, откройте уже документацию. К нему можно добавить любые подпапки и указать файл, что и сделано. Это нормально, для того функция и существует.

Comment: Переименование класса позволит избавиться от фатальной ошибки, но не решит проблему. Автор вопроса так и не указал, зачем он это делает и где определён исходный класс (а я предлагал ему сделать это в предыдущем вопросе). Скорее всего, его не устраивает функционал класса виджета в основной теме и он пытается его переопределить в дочерней. Но делать это надо иначе, отменив загрузку класса в основной теме и не переименовывая класс в дочерней. А для этого надо видеть, как класс подключается в основной теме.

Comment: да, я подключил дополнительные иконки соц сетей и убрал лишние в топ баре в этом файле